# Website look different on different monitor resolutions & css not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I am building a simple login website and I keep on running into the same problems over and over again. I would fix my css and once I switch it to my second monitor, because i am doing dual screen, it stretches out and looks bad. I researched this and found that i can add

```
$("document").ready(function() {
           var screenHeight = screen.height;
if (screenHeight < 800) {
  $('body').css('zoom', 0.);
} else {
     $('body').css('zoom', 1);
}
```

to my code but it made the media queries change position and I had to do countless editing to just get the same results. If someone can please look at my code and help me out? Basically I am just trying to get everything to look smooth on different screen resolution. And also "#img-div, #login-div" isnt allowing me to move he div's back up. It seems broken and I am sure its something to do with the media queries. Here is my code

https://jsfiddle.net/etjhyw0j/

On Second monitor
https://gyazo.com/5460eb6b46b9029945eff2cbbcc6c853

On Laptop screen
https://gyazo.com/8ddbd518e0f8d8a70af1612393939925

My screen resolution is 1366 X 768
Second screen resolution is 1920 X 1080

Comment: Have you looked into using [more specific media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) using the screen resolution or aspect ratio to compensate for the differences in your two screens?

Comment: So you mean like using "media only screen..." part?

Comment: Yupp, [here's a good resource](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/) for referencing specific devices/resolutions.

Additionally, looking at your comment on the answer below, you could look at using flexbox to center the login form vertically and setting the wrapping div to a height of screen height.

Comment: Thank you for the advice! I will look into it more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just set a decent max-width to your #container.

```
#container{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 200px;
    max-width:700px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    top: 0%;   
}
```

oh, and set the body background-size to "cover" or "contain" to prevent deforming the aspect ratio, don't use 100% 100%.

https://jsfiddle.net/etjhyw0j/4/

Comment: Thank you i see, but how about the css not letting me move the input-div or img-div? It seems like it only happens on my laptopsreen and when i put it on my second screen, it moves

Comment: I think its the media queries cause when i remove it, it moves back

Comment: @Jagr where would you like to position them?

Comment: i wanted it so the user cannot scroll down the page, like back to  150px or 100px